# White space between two flex items while copying

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For example, I have a flex container with two items in it, when I am trying to search the text inside both flex item using find no result is given.

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World!</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way where I can use flex and search the whole content of the div together like CTRL+F HelloWorld!

Comment: I think it's because of different tags, not for flex items.

Comment: even tried with the span tag, used p tag for just an example, and I think it doesn't matter the tag inside flexbox

Comment: you cannot, here is a simiar issue related to the copy/paste : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50263549/8620333 ... technically there is no word `HelloWorld!` but there is `Hello World!` (with line break)

Comment: This is not related to flexbox. It's the browser's implementation and I don't think you can bypass this. Every browser can theoretically implement the find mechanism how it wants. Consider storing the elements in the same tag, or alternatively write a "Search" utility on your website that can search for anything you like